# At what stage should acknowledgements be inserted into the paper if review is double-blind?

Tags: ethics

At what stage should acknowledgements be inserted into the paper if review is double-blind?

Is it only possible at the very end, when preparing the proof version?

Or is it possible once the paper is accepted with revisions?

By acknowledgments is meant acknowledgments to colleagues helping with some comments on previous versions of the manuscript, but also to the reviewers for their remarks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When submitting an article to a double blind review process, it is advisable to leave all potential identifiers out of the paper until the review process is finished, this would include acknowldedgments as well, see also [this instruction](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/social-science-and-medicine/policies/double-blind-peer-review-guidelines) from Elsevier.

You can indicate that there are some omitted acknowledgments by including a statement in the acknowledgement section like "The acknowldgements have been omitted in this version to maintain the integrity of the double blind peer review process", if you want the reviewers to know.

Answer (score 1):

There should be clear instructions *when* in the process your paper is to be unblinded. This includes adding author information and acknowledgements, as well as doing other smaller text changes you may want to do as part of the unblinding process (e.g., sometimes you may want to add more explicit pointers to your own previous work, which you may have removed in the submitted version in the spirit of double-blind).

If you are submitting to a journal, there are probably instructions about this on the "Author Information" (or similar) page. If you are submitting to a conference there may be instructions on the web page, or at least you will likely receive these instructions along with information how to submit your camera-ready version.